# Chart Js - Globally set bar chart color based on value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to generate a page with multiple bar charts and set the color of each globally based on a value in array!

this is the code i have so far..it works in so far as it takes one of the values and assigns it all of the bars! Where I need it to assign RED to FALSE and GREEN to TRUE

```
var win = simpleData[0].myWin;  //array containing either true or false
var myBorderColors = [];

    $.each(win, function (index, value) {
        if (value == true) {
            myBorderColors[index] = "rgba(0, 177, 106, 1)";
        } else {

            myBorderColors[index] = "rgba(207, 0, 15, 1)";
        }
});

Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = myBorderColors;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an `array` named "win" that contains `boolean` values, you could create the "myBorderColors" `array` as follows using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var myBorderColors = win.map(b => b ? "rgba(0, 177, 106, 1)" : "rgba(207, 0, 15, 1)");
```

And then use the following assignment to `Chart.defaults`.

```
Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.borderColor = myBorderColors;
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
var win = [true, false, false, true];
var myBorderColors = win.map(b => b ? "rgba(0, 177, 106, 1)" : "rgba(207, 0, 15, 1)");

Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.borderColor = myBorderColors;

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [3, 5, 4, 2],
      borderWidth: 3
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply

I'm still having the same error in that only one color is being used
I logged to the console, myBorderColors to array and it contains the right colors but they aren't being assigned to the graph

Comment: @Ger: Did you assign the border colors to `Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.borderColor`, same as I did in my code snippet?

Comment: Yes 
I applied it to 

`Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = myBorderColors`

It seems that it is reading the first value and then applying it to the entire to chart! And not reading the second value

Comment: @Ger: This is not the same object as I used.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention 
`Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.borderColor` gave an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`

so i used the `Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = myBorderColors` instead, it populated every bar in the graph as the first color in the array

Comment: @Ger: Make sure you use most recent stable version (2.9.3) of Chart.js.

Comment: that was it, thank you so much for your time! working fine now

Comment: @Ger: Glad it works for you now. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your question.